# Quelle est la différence entre « penser » et « réfléchir » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Comme mentionné dans le titre, quelle est la différence entre « penser » et « réfléchir »  ?

Comment: On a peine à se poser la question sur un strict plan linguistique, tant on est avant tout mis face à un problème *philosophique*.

Comment: Réflexion : « Retour de la pensée sur elle-même pour examiner les données d'un problème. En métaphysique, le terme signifie souvent l'action par laquelle la pensée se tourne vers ses propres opérations et facultés. » (Encyclopédie philosophique universelle, les notions philosophiques, livre 2, premières lignes de la définition de *réflexion*).

Comment: Réfléchir peut être utiliser avec un autre sens, dans le sens "réfléchir la lumière" qui signifie que la lumière rebondit sur un obstacle. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chir

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Réfléchir, c'est travailler dans sa tête. Par exemple: essayer de trouver des solutions à un problème, ou faire du calcul mental. Ça prend généralement du temps.

> J'ai beaucoup réfléchi, mais je ne trouve pas de solution.
>
> Tu parles sans réfléchir, alors tu dis n'importe quoi.
>
> Je vais réfléchir quelques jours avant de te donner ma décision.

Penser, c'est avoir une idée qui arrive dans la tête. On dit toujours « pense à quelque chose ». Et ça n'implique pas de vrai travail mental.

> J'ai beaucoup pensé à toi, aujourd'hui.
>
> Je n'ai pas pensé à acheter le pain en rentrant.
>
> J'ai pensé à une nouvelle idée pour ton projet. (Ça m'est venu sans réfléchir)

Penser sert aussi à exprimer son opinion.

> Je pense que ce candidat est le meilleur.
>
> Je pense que tu ne devrais pas déménager dans ce quartier.
>
> Je pense qu'on devrait reporter notre pique-nique, car il fera meilleur demain.

Pour exprimer son opinion sur quelque chose, on peut aussi utiliser "trouver"

> Je trouve ce tableau très beau.
>
> Je trouve qu'il fait trop froid aujourd'hui pour un pique-nique.
>
> Je trouve Paul très sympa.

Comment: @oli, are you a native speaker?

Comment: @Aerovistae, yes, I am French.

Answer (score 7):

La réflexion est un mode particulier de la pensée où celle-ci est consciemment dirigée vers l'examen d'une idée, d'une question, d'un problème.

Comment: On peut parfois aussi dire que la pensée est le résultat de la réflexion: "*J'ai réfléchi à ce problème, et (maintenant) je pense que ...*".

Comment: @Bruno, dans _je pense que..._ ce qui suit est une opinion, un avis, une croyance, pas une pensée. Le fait que _penser_ soit aussi utilisé résulte, pour moi, de la polysémie du mot, pas de la différence entre _penser_ et _réfléchir_ dans les acceptions qui sont proches. Un peu comme le fait que _réfléchir_ puisse désigner l'action d'un miroir n'est pas pertinente.

Answer (score 3):

Penser et réfléchir ne sont pas parfaitement synonymes. On peut dire *Je pense que tu as raison* mais pas *Je réfléchis que tu as raison*.

En anglais, on peut opposer *I think you're right* (Je pense que tu as raison) à *I've been thinking* (J'ai bien réfléchi).

On indique ce que l'on pense ou à qui / à quoi l'on pense (que, qui, quoi).Penser est normalement suivi d'un COD (penser quelque chose / Il y a QUE dans QUELQUE), d'une conjonctive en QUE (Je pense que tu as raison), du pronom interrogatif QUOI dans la langue familière (Tu penses quoi ? Qu'est-ce que tu en penses ? Quel est ton avis sur la question ?), ou d'un COI (Tu penses à qui ? Tu penses à quoi ?).

Penser appelle le morphème QU- de QU', QUE, QUI, QUOI, QUEL ou QUELQUE.

Réfléchir rappelle COMMENT:

Réfléchissez-bien à ma proposition / Parler sans réfléchir.

Dans *As-tu réfléchi que tu n'étais pas libre demain ?*, on sous-entend une appréciation du type "tu n'a pas bien réfléchi, tu as pris ta décision trop vite, c'est dommage, c'est malheureux, c'est préjudiciable, c'est bête". On ne s'intéresse pas au contenu de pensée (que tu étais libre demain), qui n'est pas un élément nouveau (Est-ce que tu t'es souvenu que...), mais à la qualité de ce qui y a mené (comment tu t'y es pris).

Dans *As-tu pensé que tu n'étais pas libre demain ?*, c'est la valeur informative de "que tu n'étais pas libre demain" qui prime, et non la valeur appréciative qui est remise en cause ou en question (tu n'as pas bien réfléchi).

Dans *Je pense, donc je suis*, peu importe ce que l'on pense ou comment on le pense, et peu importe les modalités de l'existence (qui je suis, comment je suis). Le verbe "penser" n'a pas de complément (penser quelque chose) comme le verbe "être" est réduit à sa fonction de verbe lexical (exister), là où dans ses autres emplois il est copule (Je suis quelqu'un, Je suis bien), ou auxiliaire (je suis parti).

Quoi qu'il en soit, le verbe "penser" est avant tout informatif, alors que le verbe "réfléchir" est avant tout appréciatif. Descartes dit "Je pense, donc je suis", et non "Je réfléchis, donc je suis", car il désire informer.

Answer (score 0):

Moi je voyais le mot « pensée » comme un fait passé, c'est à dire que lorsqu'on pense, on fait resurgir un événement déjà vécu.

Je pense à ma femme, étant dans le présent j'utilise la ou les dernières images de ma femme gardées dans ma tête et je me fais toute une scène imaginaire. Donc je ne peux penser au futur.

Mais quand je réfléchis, je cherche toujours une solution. Je veux une voiture mais je n'ai pas d'argent, alors je réfléchis à comment trouver de l'argent.
Je suis employé chez X et son entreprise est en train de faire faillite, de peur de me retrouver au chômage je réfléchis à comment rebooster le marché de l'entreprise.

Pour résumer penser est imaginaire, émotionnel et sans effort.
Réfléchir c'est tout un travail, « un vrai remède pour maigrir ».

Answer (score 0):

> Ces deux termes, souvent confondus, sont pourtant assez différents. Enfin, pas trop. De même que la banane est un fruit mais que tous les fruits ne sont pas des bananes, aussi, la réflexion est une façon particulière de penser mais toutes les pensées ne sont pas réflexions. Réfléchir, c’est travailler dans sa tête, essayer de trouver des solutions à un problème, ou faire du calcul mental. Cela prend généralement du temps. Par contre, penser, c’est lorsqu’une idée nous vient en tête; cette action ne nécessite pas forcément un effort intellectuel.

Extrait de cet article de blog: https://brieadventures.blogspot.com/2020/05/la-fameuse-difference-entre-reflechir.html

Answer (score 0):

Penser c'est de donner une idée, d'exprimer son opinion et d'imaginer quelque chose un projet etc...
Réfléchir c'est d'essayer de trouver une solution, de donner une décision et de conclure quelque chose.
Donc la vraie différence c'est que penser c'est proposer, prouver ou raisonner mais réfléchir c'est de résoudre

Comment: Malheureusement on n'est pas sûr de résoudre ce que  l'on pense quand on y réfléchit.  Bienvenue sur FL ; voici le [tour] du site.

Answer (score -1):

Originaire du bas latin, *penser* c'est peser (le pour et le contre) ; au figuratif, c'est *réfléchir* (réflexion : retour de la pensée sur elle-même pour un examen plus approfondi) . (Source Le Petit Robert)

Synonymes, ils peuvent donc être employés l'un pour l'autre, sans risque de contre-sens, surtout si l'on pense/réfléchit à ses études futures ou à quelque chose d'abstrait.

Cependant si une action ou quelque chose qui concerne les sens est en cause,

- lorsque nous sommes éveillés, le flot de la pensée est continue, passe d'un sujet à l'autre en une fraction de seconde, on pense tout le temps à quelque chose,
- lorsque l'on rencontre un problème ou une contrainte, on réfléchit à sa solution : le temps de la pensée a fait une pause pour que la réflexion s'installe (on rumine ses pensées).

"Réfléchir c'est penser et repenser à une seule chose à la fois", pourrait établir une distinction, lorsque la réflexion est liée à une action.

Comment: A noter que *penser*, au contraire de *réfléchir*, peut servir à exprimer une opinion: *Je pense que c'est mal*.

Comment: Les deux mots sont loin d'être interchangeable. Je ne peux pas former avec _réfléchir_ un équivalent à « Je pense à ma femme. » Et je ressens une très forte nuance entre « Je pense à mon avenir. » et « Je réfléchis à mon avenir. » Le premier peut être adéquat pour une rêverie, le second pas.

Comment: @Unfrancophone - tentative d'humour : Pourquoi ne pas avoir l'avis de votre femme : abstraction ou opinion, votre avenir en dépend peut-être que vous y réfléchissiez ou que vous y pensiez.

Comment: Cette réponse est selon moi la plus pertinente.

Answer (score -4):

On pense au passé et on réfléchit à l'avenir.